# Data input/output on Basys3 board's USB port

Tags: usb, vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to configure/write VHDL code that would let me output or input data from the USB port on a Basys3 FPGA board.  Problem is I have yet to found any threads or questions that talk about this topic.

The nearest thing to an answer I've found is this:

[Provide input data to FPGA using USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137143/provide-input-data-to-fpga-using-usb%C3%A7)

and it does not contain what I'm looking for.
  Any clues anyone¿?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Basys3 board has a usb-uart bridge chip as described in the [reference manual](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/basys-3/reference-manual#usb-uart_bridge_serial_port).  This will appear to a PC (or any device with a usb host and the appropriate usb-serial drivers) as a virtual com port.  Sending data to and from a PC com port is quite easy.

You will need a uart implementation on the FPGA.  There are lots of example designs on the web.  One way is to implement a soft core [microblaze processor](https://reference.digilentinc.com/learn/programmable-logic/tutorials/basys-3-getting-started-with-microblaze/start) with a uart peripheral in the FPGA.  This example looks like it includes foundation for the functionality you desire.

The simplest implementation from the PC side is using a terminal program such as [putty](http://www.putty.org/), [Tera Term](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/) or [realterm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/).  Most languages include com(serial) port libraries or bindings.  This type of interface tops out at a raw bandwidth of around 3-12Mbits per second depending on the drivers and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual for the Basys 3 board. It will explain how you can interface with USB devices plugged into the USB port. Be warned, however, that your options are pretty limited.

Short version: if you plug in a USB mouse or keyboard, they will be exposed to your design as an emulated PS/2 device. USB storage devices can be used to configure the FPGA. Other devices are not supported.

Comment: I've read it, problem is that it only explains how to use peripherals connected to the board.  It does not talk about connecting a transmitter(in my case) or sending/receiving data(even if it is raw data) for the program in execution.

Comment: What do you mean by "a transmitter"? If it's a USB device that isn't a keyboard or a mouse, though, it won't be recognized, and can't be used.